# mysql table with auto increment column restarting

Tags: mysql

The title is probably not very obvious, I'll try to explain what I want.
I found lots of questions like mine here, but the answers didn't help me.

Let's say I have this table and it's fields in a video's website:

```
Comments
ID | IDuser | IDvideo | comment
```

I want to make my primary key a combination of ID and IDuser fields.
IDuser comes from the user table.
ID is an auto_increment column.

But I want it to work like this example.

```
1 | 2 | 3 | "this is the first comment of user 2 in the video 3"
2 | 2 | 4 | "this is the first comment of user 2 in the video 4"
3 | 2 | 4 | "this is the second comment of user 2 in the video 4"
1 | 3 | 3 | "this is the first comment of user 3 in the video 3"
```

You see? It's like every user has his own auto_increment range.

I want to do this because otherwise the first column would have a very large number, because for every comment you would have a sequential ID.

Do you have any suggestion for me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think large numbers will a problem for you ?

Comment: I don't know. It doesn't feel right. What is the biggest numeric value you can assign to a field in MySQL?

Comment: If you just use `unsigned int` (4294967295) and you want have your page to run 30years then the number would be enough for 4 comments every second. With an `unsigned bigint` you can have thousands of comments per second, but I think for both you will have other problems then.

Comment: You are right. It's like jgabriel said. It's enough to use unsigned int or bigint. It won't be a problem. I don't think I have to worry about this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, you *can't* use AutoIncrement that way.
2. Second, you *shouldn't*.

*AutoIncrement* is used to create an `ID` row for a table. Each row **SHOULD** have it's own unique ID.

If you want to have a *relative ID* for users comments, you should create a new collumn whose value should be set manually.

Good luck!

**EDIT**
In your case your table should be something like this:

- `id` **INT** *Unsigned AutoIncrement*
- `idUser` **INT** *Unsigned Indexed Foreignkey*
- `idVideo` **INT** *Unsigned Indexed Foreignkey*
- `idUserComment` **INT** *Unsigned*
- `Comment` *Varchar*

But i would not recommend you to have a relative ID. Unless it would make some sense for your application

Comment: This way I would still have to use the column ID. Imagine that I have a billion comments in the database. This column would have to assign a value of 1.000.000.000 and even more. 
This is what I'm trying to avoid.
Maybe the best way is to use id, idUser, idUserComment as you said, as the primary key and remove the ID column.
You think this is a wrong way of doing it?

Comment: As you can see, in a `int`, using 4 bytes only per `id`, you can have a number up to 4.29 billion. If that is not enough, you can set your `id` collumn to `bigint` which can handle `integer` numbers up to 18 quintillion without any problem...

Comment: And if quintillions don't seem enough, you can use PgSQL `numeric` datatype. It can handle up to 131072 digits

Comment: And remember that searching for a row using a _PrimaryKey_ with `INT` value is _probably_ much faster than searching for a row using an _indexed_ `int` and a _ForeignKey_ `int` as conditionals

Comment: well, Ok, you convinced me. You are right. It doens't seem a problem to use an unique column as auto_increment for all users and all comments.

Comment: :D Any other question regarding this subject ?

Comment: Not at all. Thank you very much. Now I'm reading through to learn the best way to make a multiple language website, using PHP. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Although, as jgabriel is saying, you should probably not do it, I do see some value in what you're trying to achieve.

However, you may want to ask yourself "Why would a unique ID still be useful?" Well... Because each time you'll reference a comment, you'll need (ID, UserID) instead of just (ID). That means all references need 2 columns in any other table that reference your comments.... This being said:

---

The way to do it is to put the ID in the users table:

```
Users
UserID | LastCommentID | ...
123    | 0             | ...
```

You initialize that "Last Comment ID" to zero (0) meaning the user did not post any comment.

When you post a comment for a user, you just do something like this:

```
UPDATE users SET LastCommentID = LastCommentID + 1 WHERE UserID = 123
SELECT LastCommentID FROM users WHERE UserID = 123
```

And use that value.

You probably don't have to worry about locking mechanism since a user should never be able to post two comments simultaneously.

A clear advantage, speed wise, you do not need to count the number of comments a user made to know how many comments a user posted. You just read the LastCommentID (although if you do not want to count deleted or hidden comments, that may not be of much use.)

Comment: That would be useful if he is searching only if the user has commented or what is his last comment. If he is trying to have a _timeline_ of the users comments, it would be better to have an extra collumn at the comments table.

Comment: The LastCommentID is the ID he is talking about in his table sample.